# Context menu using dojo dgrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

How to create context menu using dojo dgrid?
Actually looking for context menu on dgrid, which should appear after "Right Click"of the mouse over row of the grid.

Answer (score 4):

There is no ready plug-in that can do that, you can see that on the documentation [here](http://dgrid.io/)  there is a comparison table. but there is a a listener that can help you create your own plug in.

```
grid.on(".dgrid-row:contextmenu", function(evt){ 
    evt.preventDefault(); // prevent default browser context menu 
    var item = grid.row(evt).data; 
    // item is the store item 
});
```

you can also read the documentation [here](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.15/doc/usage/Working-with-Events.md)

Comment: Thank you so much dori..I thought there will be some readymade pluggin available. Anyway I will try to customize this above code.

Comment: can you please vote up or accept my answer if it was helpful. Thank you